# pstricks and tikz packages conflicting with other packages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, pstricks, linguistics

Why is it that whenever I add \usepackage{pstricks} or \usepackage{tikz}, I always get the error below?

> Latex Error:
>   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty:60 TeX
>   capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
>
> Latex Error:
>   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty:60 ==>
>   Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

However, if I try to compile a document with (only) those packages in a separate file, no problem!

It seems as if these packages conflict with my existing packages (listed below).

Any ideas would be very much appreciated! Thanks a lot.

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{gb4e} 
 \usepackage{tipa} 
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{slashbox}
 \usepackage{arydshln}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{makeidx}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
```

Here is the code that produces the problem (with all other text removed)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{gb4e} \usepackage{tipa} \usepackage{setspace} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{multirow} \usepackage{lscape} \usepackage{slashbox} \usepackage{arydshln} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{float} \usepackage{makeidx} \usepackage{enumitem} %\usepackage{pstricks} %\usepackage{tikz} \setcounter{part}{-1} \setcounter{subsection}{0} %%%% LaTeX209: %\documentstyle[a4,11pt,gb4e]{article} %% \def\bs{$\backslash$} \frenchspacing\parskip1.2ex \parindent0pt \def\bit{\vskip.05\baselineskip\hspace*{1em}\hangindent4em\hangafter1} \title{A grammatical description of Muylaq' Aymara} \author{Matt Coler} \date{} \makeindex \begin{document}

%\begin{tikzpicture} %{\usebox{\test}}; %\end{tikzpicture}

\color{white} %\color{black} % activate to see bounding box \fboxsep=0pt   
        % this figure is 50mm by 50mm
        \newsavebox{\gaussians}
        \savebox{\gaussians}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.5,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.5);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\gaussianss}
        \savebox{\gaussianss}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.3,1.5);
        \draw (-0.27,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.3,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.45);
        \draw (-0.2,0.45) -- (-0.6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\gaussiansss}
        \savebox{\gaussiansss}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.5,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.5);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.65,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.4,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (0.5,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (1.8,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (2.4,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\oneline}
        \savebox{\oneline}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        %\tikz\draw (1,1) node{$\sigma$} -- (2,2) node{B};
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (0.7,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (2.3,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (3.75,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (5.2,0) node {\usebox{\oneline}};
        \draw (6.35,0) node {\usebox{\gaussianss}};
        \draw (9.5,0) node {\usebox{\gaussiansss}};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{picture}(100,100)
        \color{black} % for text 
        \put(-3,93){\Large{/mun}(a)}
        \put(52,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(68,93){\Large{t'(a)}}
        \put(95,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(110,93){\Large{k(a)}}
        \put(137,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(153,93){\Large{t}}
        \put(165,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(183,93){\Large{t(i)/}} 
        \put(232,93){\Large{[mun + t'+k+t+t]}} 
        \end{picture}
        %\begin{tikzpicture} 
        %\psset{unit=1mm}
        %\color{black} % for text
        %\draw (-4.4,1.4) node{/mun};
        %%\draw node{/mun(a) + t'(a) + k(a) + t + t(i)/};
        %%\draw (7.6,0) node{[mun + t' + k + t + t]};
        %\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add some *minimal* code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Make the example shorter! Remove all packages which have nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving `gb4e` as the last called package. Moreover, you have two instances of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Here's the working example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tipa} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % only one instance
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gb4e} % put gb4e here

\begin{document}
 Hello world.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Strangely, however, if I do that, it compiles but with an error: "Latex Error: ./gb4e-doc-final1.tex:621 LaTeX Error: File `waveforms' not found." -- (repeats for each image file)... If I comment out the pstricks package it compiles just fine (though the line drawing above doesn't work)

Comment: Can you please edit the example the example above? It has various basic code typos. If I try to compile it I get several errors. I put the code from the example above from \color{white} to \end{document} and it compiles without errors but the result seems to be not what your looking for: http://imgur.com/CgmDVk7

Comment: P.S.: probably it would be better if you should post another question with a new MWE.